Excel cell seems to be empty, but when double clicked it then is not counted any more but looks the same
I have a large amount of data (about 200 columns of 53 rows) and need to find totals, number of values below, percentage failure rates etc. all my calcs seem to be worked is expected, however I have run into a strange issue.
I have a formula which counts how many cells have something in and ignore N/A entries:
=COUNTA(HP12:HP65) - COUNTIF(HP12:HP65, "N/A")

This seems to work, but when checking this, I found an example of a cell which appears to be empty (if I copy the cell into notepad, it has no text, no spaces and I can't seem to see anything being at all), however for some reason this cell is being counted as having something in it.
When I double click the cell, then click on another cell, the count at the top reduces by 1.

This is what is in the cell if I paste it here between the <> there is nothing here.
If I look at it in the top section where you can edit the cell at the top, there is nothing there.
I am worried I may have other instances of this in my document that are being counted but are in fact empty.
The strange thing is, that if I copy the columns with the formula to another sheet i can copy the issue as well, then if i double click on the cell it acts the same, so I'm guessing this means there is something in this cell.
Saving the document doesn't seem to remove the error, no does forcing calculations.
Any ideas what might be going on with this cell?

Are you using any VBA stuff (macro)? I have the same thing in my sheet, where I copy data output from a formula and special paste the values in a new sheet. Since they resulted in "" from the formula, they appear empty. If I do ISBLANK() on them, it says FALSE, but when I double click them, it turns to TRUE. However, for me it's not an issue.

Sounds like an unprintable character.  Some software doesn't handle nulls well, so you get lazy developers who will use an unprintable character instead of a NULL to work around the issue.  That way the data looks empty, but it really isn't.  Check the cell contents using a LEN function.  If it returns 0, then try using VBA to check the length of the contents of the cell.

Try the solution in https://superuser.com/questions/654358/remove-pseudo-blanks-in-excel?rq=1

@paul Thanks very much for the link, this got me pretty much to the solution, then with some chatGPT i was able to get the following VBA macro to clear all the pseudo-blank cells and make them fully blank:
Sub clearEmptyValues()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If Not IsEmpty(cell) And Trim(cell.Value) = "" Then
cell.Formula = vbNullString
End If
Next cell
End Sub

With the following VBA macro i was able to clear out the pseudo-blank cells:
Sub clearEmptyValues()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And Trim(cell.Value) = "" Then
            cell.Formula = vbNullString
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


The solution here is to copy the whole range and paste back values only. If it doesn't help, use a new column with formula =HP12:HP65 then copy this range and paste back values only. Then clear HP12:HP65 and paste values onto it.
It looks like a known feature when data come not the from manual input can recognizes as text.

You could try this with your data and see whether those "empty" cells are excluded:
=SUM(IF(ISNA(HP12:HP65), 0, N(LEN(HP12:HP65) > 0)))

Or with trimming:
=SUM(IF(ISNA(HP12:HP65), 0, N(LEN(TRIM(HP12:HP65)) > 0)))

N( is used to convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0
